# Android application depending on Google Voice Search

Tags: android, dependencies

I am currently creating an application for a city in China. It needs spoken input and they like the google voice search because it is very accurate. The problem is on Chinese phones you can't find Google Voice Search. Is it possible to send it with my package to include it? In China it is impossible to connect to the Play store. Because i am currently in China google is not working very well and i cannot manage to find something about this topic.

I hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't possible to embed Google Voice Search within your application package.

If you are really ambitious you may be able to build some subset of the voice input libraries from the Android open source tree and package that, but it could easily be quite difficult to get it right, and its not clear how much of the voice processing can be done on the device.

Comment: Hi Femi,
Thanks for your answer. I think the chinese version of the play store has something like the voice search package. I can give a message to the user that it is not installed and in order to use you need the following link. Thx!